# Execute script after package installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Now, I there is `postinstall` to run a script after

```
npm install
```

However, I am looking for a way to run a script after installing a single package

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Is this possible? If so, does this work on Windows and is there a way to get the name of the installed package (`jquery` in the given example)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't see this on the `package.json` [features](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

It is therefore possible to do in the prestart for instance but jquery won't be in the devDependencies that way:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "1.3.x",
    "uglifyjs": "2.4.10",
    ... your other dependencies 
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install jquery@#.#.# ; <yourcommand> ; npm install",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem as I want the script to run after any package is installed :/